# Are upvotes on comments also recorded somewhere?

Tags: support, comments, upvotes, comment-votes

Is there a way to list down all the comments a user has ever made, along with their upvote count?

Or, as the reputation history of the logged in user can be seen by visiting [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), is there such a link that also records the upvotes on comments?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The site user interface doesn't have this feature, but it can be queried using SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer).

From [*Can I view a list of my “great comments”, perhaps in my profile?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130908/185667), just fill your user ID and change site if necessary:

> https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66765/my-most-popular-comments

<sub>Related: [Am I really a pundit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133882/185667)</sub>

Comment: That query can be *"improved"* if you replace `PostId as [Post Link]` with `Id as [Comment Link]`.

Comment: And here the improved version: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/249171/my-most-popular-comments?UserId=1

Answer (score 2):

You can also utilize the API to get all comments a user has posted.

[This](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-users#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&ids=2912665&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) link shows comments made by the original poster on Stack Overflow. The `score` is the number of upvotes a comment has received.

You'll utilize the `/users/{ids}/comments` end point for this call where the `{ids}` is the list of user IDs you want to pull comments for.