# Why is there no reputation on meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta

The title is self explanatory. Moreover, why did the creators made it to be this way? What was in their mind, and why did they finally chose to use the reputation from the base site?

Comment: Why *should* there be reputation on meta?

Comment: Because people spend their time writing useful answers here as well!

Comment: That's just an opinion.  Which is the point of meta, opinions are not answers.

Comment: @binaryBaBa The kinds of people that come to meta to answer questions are not the kinds of people that do it for Imaginary Internet Points.

Comment: @HansPassant Not always! For instance, what will you call this (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277271/2912665) - opinion or answer?

Comment: There is recognition through tag score and badges.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Exactly my point! If tags and badges were decided to be used, why not reputation?

Comment: @Servy The question is not regarding users, instead it is regarding the creators! What were they thinking?

Comment: @binaryBaBa They were thinking that the contributors wouldn't be motivated by earning imaginary internet points.

Comment: @Servy That sounds like an answer!

Comment: Take a look at [this question about voting on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272742#272742).  Since the voting culture is different on meta, having rep like main site rep doesn't really make sense (at least to me).

Comment: @binaryBaBa meta is murder. That is why.

Comment: If reputation existed on meta: [How to calculate per site meta reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172242/185667)

Comment: UPVOTES AND UPVOTES

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Meta sites are places where people come to discuss issues, bugs, suggestions and so on.

Tying those to reputation means that some people might not share opinions/suggestions they know may not be popular, simply for fear of losing reputation.

We don't want that. We want people to post what they think and not get hung up on reputation when talking about the site/platform.

Comment: Note: what is now Meta Stack Exchange used to be Meta Stack Overflow. It did (and MSE still does) come with its own reputation. And far too often people would indeed throw a hissy fit over lost reputation or privileges when all they did was make an unpopular suggestion.

Comment: Thank you @oded! I was looking for this answer, and with your words: "We want people to post what they think and not get hung up on reputation when talking about the site/platform." I'm just have found was I'm looking for. (cit.) ;-)

Comment: So why does MSE uses a reputation system if basically it is another Meta site?

Comment: @Luis - in all other metas users inherit reputation from the parent site. The reputation is used for privileges etc also on the meta site. MSE doesn't have such a Q&A parent site.

Comment: I understand the part that MSE does not have an actual parent site but by being like it is it violates your own answer. Is such "violation" a desirable feature of MSE or just something that unfortunately MSE has to stick to?

Comment: @Luis - it is a technical limitation that we chose to stay with instead of having lots of workarounds and conditionals in our codebase. MSE has been setup to have relaxed requirements to allow discussions (reputation required, hard to hit question ban etc...)